# Android DataBinding 3.0.1 calling method on observable variable causes wrong code generated that leads to NPE

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I've written such layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable name="vm"
                  type="example.Vm" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/root"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                   android:onClick="@{() -> vm.observableField.buttonClicked()}"
                   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

In onClick parameter I'm calling method on `example.Vm` that has such field:

```
public ObservableField<SomeClass> observableField = new ObservableField<>();
```

Android databinding generated such code:

```
// Listener Stub Implementations
// callback impls
public final void _internalCallbackOnClick(int sourceId , android.view.View callbackArg_0) {
    // localize variables for thread safety
    // vm != null
    boolean vmJavaLangObjectNull = false;
    // vm.someClassObservable
    android.databinding.ObservableField<biz.i20.fire_android.feature.act.SomeClass> vmSomeClassObservable = null;
    // vm
    biz.i20.fire_android.feature.actscreen.ActVm vm = mVm;
    // vm.someClassObservable != null
    boolean vmSomeClassObservableJavaLangObjectNull = false;
    // vm.someClassObservable.get()
    biz.i20.fire_android.feature.act.SomeClass vmSomeClassObservableGet = null;



    vmJavaLangObjectNull = (vm) != (null);
    if (vmJavaLangObjectNull) {


        vmSomeClassObservable = vm.someClassObservable;

        vmSomeClassObservableJavaLangObjectNull = (vmSomeClassObservable) != (null);
        if (vmSomeClassObservableJavaLangObjectNull) {


            vmSomeClassObservableGet.buttonClicked();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here, databinding compiler initializes variable `vmSomeClassObservableGet` with `null` value, and then does not get it's value from `vmSomeClassObservable`.
I can fix this issue by explicitly calling `.get()` on `ObservableField`, however it leads to compiler warning:

> Warning:warning: Do not explicitly call 'get()' on ObservasbleFields
>   in an expression. This support will be removed soon.
>   'vm.observableField.get()'

How can i fix this issue? Seems like bug.

Comment: That looks like a bug. You should only see that warning if you use "observableField.get()" in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the class with `ObservableField` in order to call it from your layout.

I would replace your field with:

```
public SomeClass observableField = referenceToSomeClass;
```

(I would rename `observableField` to a more appropriate name, but I left it like this to make the answer more clear)

Comment: I've wrapped it because i need to wrap it due to my task, of course.

Comment: Also, i've renamed fields to show the principle and not to expose my project information because it is under NDA.

Comment: About the field naming, I meant I would rename it after the suggested change. It is clear that `SomeClass` and other names are choose to illustrate your point :) That being said, it feels a bit strange that the click method is in an observable field. I agree that looks like a bug. A possible workaround without the warning will be to have a specific variable for click handlers and similar things, implementing a specific `interface`. I cannot think on a better answer without knowing the specifics of `SomeClass`.

Comment: I was about to suggest you to open a bug, but I see you've already done it :) Linking it here to be able to track it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70145419

Comment: btw, can you star both of that issues, please?